# cocos2d-js updating project

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-js

To create a project with cocos2d-js the procedure is simple:

- install cocos2d-js
- run `setup.py`
- create the project with `cocos new`

But is there a procedure to update a project to use the latest cocos2d-js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could replace the contents of the `frameworks` folder in your project by hand with the latest sources.

If you use Cocos Code IDE, it can automatically update projects for you.

Comment: You are absolutely right! Cocos Code IDE can update the project! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the upgrade guide: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/docs/manual/framework/html5/release-notes/v3.0rc0/upgrade-guide/en